# Is there a term for when a movie(or novel) makes reference to the books title?

Tags: reference

As the title says, I am curious. Numerous movies and books make use of this, and I would like my curiosity satisfied. On a side note, this term will aid in my writing assignment, where we are discussing *The Beggar Maid*, which has the title directly spoken aloud to the main character...

Comment: In philosophy it would be referred to as "self reflection".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TVTropes.org refers to this practice as [Title Drop](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TitleDrop):

> If a line of dialogue is the title of the episode, movie, or book, it
>   obviously must have some great significance. If it sounds completely
>   random, that just means the true meaning of the title has yet to be
>   revealed. So when a character is heard using the title in dialogue,
>   the audience sits up and takes notice, because the scriptwriter has
>   just planted a neon sign that flashes **THIS CONVERSATION IS IMPORTANT**...
>
> Often, the Title Drop will finally explain why the episode/book/etc is
>   called that way to begin with. If this explanation comes by showing
>   instead of by telling (i.e. it is not actually spoken aloud by any of
>   the characters), then it's **[The Namesake](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheNamesake)**.
>
> A second variety of Title Drop occurs when the title of a work is used
>   as the last line spoken. Here, it's not nearly as big and flashy and
>   important as the first variety, but it still explains things to the
>   audience a bit more. You can probably find these mainly in thriller
>   works, where it makes you sit up and think (and adds a bit of drama to
>   the ending). It's also common in plays that were written during the
>   Victorian era.

Sometimes the title is selected because that line of dialogue is significant:

> Title Drops aren't always deliberate or premeditated (i.e. the writer
>   takes the title and inserts it for effect). Sometimes the creative
>   process runs the other way, and a phrase from the body of the work
>   will be picked out and used as the title (sometimes the title is the
>   last thing to be nailed down).